# Error in installing sqldf package

Tags: r, package, sqldf

I tried installing the sqldf package using the following code:

```
install.packages("sqldf")
```

However, I get the following error.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'RSQLite/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Is there a way to fix this?

The session info -

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RODBC_1.3-13

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2
```

Comment: Do you have SQlite installed ?

Comment: `setInternet2(TRUE)`, and check if you have enough space, then try again.

Comment: @ODelibalta I don't! Which version of SQLite should I install? Thank you!

Comment: @zx8754, I tried it. It didn't work. Got the same error. Thank you

Comment: Hard to guess, maybe it would help if you add `sessionInfo()` to your post? Also, if you haven't seen it already, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884) for other suggestions.

Comment: @zx8754 I have added the session info to my post. I'm going through the link you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Can you install other packages, or is this `RSQLite` specific? Have you tried running R as an administrator?

Comment: Can you check if you have access to `.libPaths()`? I tried on my PC with the same sessionInfo (but UK locale) it works fine.

Comment: @Gregor I didn't trouble installing packages like dplyr or ggplot2. I had this trouble only with SQLDF and Ratte. Yes, I tried running it as an administrator but still encountered similar issues. Thanks.

Comment: If you installed the new RSQLite 2.0 then you will need to install the new sqldf 0.4-11; otherwise, if you are want to use the old sqldf 0.4-10 then use a version of RSQLite older than 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue too. This error is in dependence of the BH library.
First update to 3.4.1 RC because 3.4.0 will fail in validation TRUE/FALSE package.
Download the BH library directly from de R CRAN Library. Unpack using 7.zip and copy folder to library in R folder.

Comment: See my comment to the queston.